# Reupload the document (update)

Tags: 2007, development, document-library, file-upload, updatelistitems

I'm writing now code agains the document library, that code adds files to the document library. Basically what I want to do is, when the particular file already exists in the document library with the same name, i don't want to get an error message, but i want to update it.

By updating I mean, i want to upload the new document instead of an old one, but not like deleting whole item and then uploading file and all metadata etc, i just want to update the file and also i have versioning on the document library so basically it should increase in version ...

Any idea how to do that? Because now when i programmatically try to upload a file with the same name I get an error ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link might help you. Refer it.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/c99e6161-66e9-4aea-953a-16f64f816cd7

Comment: Oh right, how could i forget about the overwrite ... thanks for the help

Comment: yes thats right...always...